# Which boolean expression gets evaluated first in an IF statement containing an OR operation?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, if-statement

In the following statement, in VC++, which boolean expression gets evaluated first? Also, do they both get evaluated?

```
if( (X==Y) || (Z==T))
{
 //code here
}
```

Comment: Is this homework? Look up short cut operators.

Comment: What are the types of X, Y, Z, and T?

Comment: Not homework. Needed a quick answer for work. Thanks guys..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They're evaluated left-to-right and if the first one is true the expression short-circuits and the second one is not evaluated.

Comment: Operators evaluating left-to-right are also called left-associative.

Comment: Note that short-circuit logic only applies for the builtin `||` . If there was any operator overloading silliness going on here, that wouldn't happen.

Answer (score 9):

If the built-in `||` operator is used, then `X == Y` will be evaluated before `Z == T` is evaluated.  The built-in `||` operator is evaluated left-to-right and it short-circuits, so if `X == Y` is true, then by definition `X == Y || Z == T` is true so `Z == T` is not evaluated.

However, the `||` operator can also be overloaded, and if it is overloaded it does not short circuit.  Tf a user-defined overload of `||` is selected for the use of `||` here, then both `X == Y` and `Z == T` are evaluated, even if `X == Y` is true.  It is rare that the `||` operator is overloaded as it can lead to unintuitive code.  It's just important to remember that it doesn't behave the same way as the built-in operator.

Comment: Actually, with some work you can make a || overload that retains effective short-circuit behavior.  Lazy operators and such...

Comment: Yes, the caveat about user-defined types and overloaded operators is important!

Comment: @Noah:  Yes, you could even overload all of the operators to have them build an expression tree and then only evaluate the full expression when its result is used.  However, that doesn't change the fact that you don't get actual, language-supported short circuiting.

Comment: @Noah: I would love to see an || overload that doesn't evaluate foo() in `true || foo()`

Comment: `struct foo_eval { bool evaluate() { ... } }; foo_eval foo() { return foo_eval(); } bool operator || (bool b, foo_eval const& fe) { return b || fe.evaluate(); }` - of course, none of that is necessary since your code segment works that way out of the box.

Answer (score 4):

The first expression left to right will always be evaluated (in this case `(X==Y)`), the second expression (again left to right and in this case `(Z==T)`) will only be evaluated if the first is false. This is known as [Short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Comment: Except that they're not statements.

Comment: I couldn't give a +1 for this even though answering the question, "Which expression is evaluated first," with, "The first statement," did make me laugh.

Answer (score 1):

X==Y will be evaluated first. If true and since the condition is an OR, nothing else on the line will be evaluated.